# Problem with image toggle on dynamically loaded Bootstrap collapse panel with nested collapse panel

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap-3, nested, panel

Can someone help with a dynamically loaded collapse panel with a nested dynamically loaded collapse panel? The issue I'm having is the image toggles for the outer and inner panels.  The collapse part is working fine, the image toggle is what I'm having problems with. Here is something similar to what I have.  Please forgive any syntax errors, I had to make up an example that is similar to mine.

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach(AccountModel aModel in Model.AccountModels)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-target="#@aModel.Id" data-toggle="collapse" role="button">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        @aModel.Description
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>      
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="@aModel.Id">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @foreach(TransactionModel tModel in aModel.Transactions)
                    {
                        //nested collapse panel                 
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" data-target="#@tModel.Id" data-toggle="collapse" role="button">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                        @tModel.Description
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>              
                        <div class=panel-collapse collapse" id="@tModel.Id">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>Some details</p>
                                <p>More details</p>
                            <div>
                        <div>           
                    }       
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
<script>
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus:first").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
    stopPropagation();
  }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus:first").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
    stopPropagation();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Found a simple solution after doing some console logging.  Changing $(this). parent () to $(this).prev() fixed the problem.